# Multimedia assets management application

Tags: audio, file-management, video-editing, audio-editing, digital-asset-management

I am looking for an app for managing multimedia files, i.e. image assets, video clips, sound clips etc.

Platforms: Windows [must], but a big plus if it could run on MacOS and Linux too.

Required features:

- GUI;
- preview handle file types: audio (at least mp3, ogg, wav), video (at least mp4, mov, webm, wmv, mkv, avi), images (at least png, webp, jpg, svg);
- import files existing on the drive (e.g. by dropping a folder, containing a few sub-folders, each of which have 100-200 short MP3 files) without the need to create a separate copy of the file or destroying the folder hierarchy it's originally in (from the perspective of the OS) - I expanded upon this below, when describing how Eagle app works
- preview/play the file within the GUI;
- easily locate the file on the drive (should open MS Explorer with the folder in which the file is in);
- ability to add a comment with a timestamp to audio and video files;
- ability to search with filenames, or within the content of existing comments with timestamps (e.g. I have a few short clips, to clip abc.mp4 at 1:03 I added comment "Change of the scene", and a few days later I try to find this clip, I don't remember its filename, but I enter "scene change" in the searchbar, and the file with exact timestamp comes up);
- ability to handle unavailable files (e.g. in case of external HDD) - the app doesn't have to cache video/audio, but should be able to store info about the location of the file (e.g. UUID/label of the external drive) + be able to still utilize search features (including comments, even if preview unavailable at the moment)

I found Eagle (eagle.cool) which pretty much satisfy most of the requirements, but I hate that importing to "library" creates a separate copy of the files, and stores them all pretty much in one folder - referring to those files from other programs (i.e. Adobe CC, like Premiere Pro or After Effects) is just awful. And having multiple copies of e.g. 300GB of video footage and few hundreds of sound effects/soundtracks for an indie movie is for sure not a storage-friendly solution.

The solution described above, that I'm seeking for is pretty much a tool that any video editor, youtubers, streamers, content creators, game designer/dev, motion designer, content marketers, social media marketer or any other multimedia artist would utilize. Any recommendations meeting those requirements are welcomed.